# Regex Match 6 Letter String With Chars and Number and No positive look around

Tags: regex

I know there are several similar answers, but I am struggling to find one that fits my use case.

I need a regex to extract IDs that are 6 characters long and have a mix of numbers and characters.

The IDs will start with one of the following chars `[eEdDwWaA]`

I have had some solutions that have nearly worked, but the tool I want to plug this regex into does NOT support positive look around and every answer seems to use this.

The string I need to find can be anywhere in text and will either be preceded by a whitespace or a backslash.

Example of what I would want to match is `eh3geh` (case insensitive)

Here is what I have so far  `[eEdDwWaA](?:[0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9],{5})[a-z0-9]*`

This works for the most part but it is not consistently matching and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You require five commas with `,{5}`, is that intentional?

Comment: No that was me trying to limit the match to 6 characters long

Comment: Without a lookahead support, you will have to spell out all possibilities.

Comment: Can you use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)? If so, you could match what you don't want [but capture what you need](https://regex101.com/r/FVSJqi/1) and process the captures of group one on program-side. Please provide more information, what tool, how input can look like, what's the right boundary...

Comment: So `e12345` or `abcdef` are not valid identifiers?

Comment: Hope this helps : /[\s\\]([eEdDwWaA][a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/gi

Comment: @bobblebubble I can use capturing groups. Nick, e12345 is valid but abcdef is not. Must have at least one number and on char

Comment: @Roshan that isn't quite working. Has an unmatched parenthesis. When I add one at the beginning the error goes away  but it then matches too much

Comment: @Joe Something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/jnO9rR/1) works for you? (you need to get *group 1* matches on program-side, check if *group 1* not null/empty)

Comment: @bobblebubble That looks super close!! I think this is just about there. How can I tweak this to end a match on a whitespace or newline? I don't need it to be able to pull out substrings, could I use something like `\s` as an anchor?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a word boundary `\b` [like this?](https://regex101.com/r/n6jdgE/1) You can use a space, but if it's also preceded by space, and they are only separated by one space you [won't get overlapping matches](https://regex101.com/r/dE8TZJ/1). That's why I asked for showing some real input sample.

Comment: @bobblebubble Yes I can use that. I have applied it and I think that this is working as expected. I just plugged it into the system and hopefully we start to see result soon. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Let me know if it works, I can put that as an answer or you answer yourself. 

Comment: @bobblebubble  I'll let you know - If you post the answer I'll accept it that way you can get the Stack Skrilla  :)

Comment: @joe I see the escape character in character set is causing issue when pasting in the comments : any try this /[\s\\\]([eEdDwWaA][a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/gi

Comment: @joe always be explicit with the matches you want , helps prevent false positives.

Comment: @bobblebubble You could even bring it down to a character class `[ \\]` :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird amazing, because you write and see what I was just thinking myself and changing at the very moment! (no kidding) 

Comment: If *case insensitive* matching is needed, just extend `[a-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]` or use [`i` modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html) if available.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use a lookahead an idea is to [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) using [The Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).

> The trick is that we match what we don't want on the left side of the alternation (the `|`), then we capture what we do want on the right side....

```
[\\ ](?:.[a-z]{5}|([eEdDwWaA][a-z0-9]{5}))\b
```

- `.[a-z]{5}` we don't want only letters (left side)
- `|(`...`)` but capture what we need to *group one* (righte side)

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QbHssl/1)

Get the captures of *group 1* on program-side (where group not null/empty).

Comment: Now that it has been in use for a few hours I am realizing that this does not work. 2 issues - 1) it is matching words that begin with any letter. 2) it is matching words without numbers. Thoughts on what I can try?

Comment: @Joe That's the idea behind it. Match what you don't want but CAPTURE what you want. The matches are in [**capture group 1** (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/imXYUZ/1). If group 1 is empty, don't count/use the match. That's why I asked if you can use capturing groups. Check on program-side. Read more about [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: @Joe If you can't use that, as mentioned you'd probably need to write all possible combinations, such as: [`[\\ ][eEdDwWaA](?:\d[a-z\d]{4}|[a-z]\d[a-z\d]{3}|[a-z]{2}\d[a-z\d]{2}|[a-z]{3}\d[a-z\d]|[a-z]{4}\d)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/uBOWJ7/1) (for casless matching, use with [`i` modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html))